# How to handle same user loging into application using different machine or different browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to handle same user logging into application using different machine or different browser.
This is one solution i am planning to do:-
When user log in i am going to save the session id in the database and user logging out clear the field.

If user already logged in and he/she try to logging in again from different machine then he/she will be redirected to the Multiple user logged in page.In this page he/she can cancel or force the session id to clear and redirect to the log in page.

Here one problem is, If user click on the browser close button then session id will not clear and when they try to log in again the user will be redirect to the Multiple User Lo-gin page.

Whether this is a good solution or any other method i have to follow?

Comment: If you're working in a Windows environment, you should take a look at what Active Directory can offer you.

Comment: What task are you trying to solve? What's the reason to only have one active user's session?

Comment: Try to block Concurrent Logins. Same user should login only one at a time.

Comment: Can't you just expire the session/cookie after x minutes?

Comment: @dbaseman:-its already set.What i will do when same user log in from different machine at the same time with in session active time ?

Comment: @JobyKurian log them out of the first session?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few suggestions:

1. Have your application send frequent ping messages (every 15 seconds 
   or something like that) and if the server doesn't receive a message 
   within a given timeout period expire that session.
2. Handle window onunload or onbeforeunload events in javascript.
3. Have a cookie with more agressive timeout

Comment: Picking one of the solutions above depends on your situation and what business logic you want to execute in the different scenarios. For example if you have reliable connection or not and if you want to handle these cases.